# ¿Por que mi app no compila cuando agrego un Imageview?

Tags: android

Sucede que cuando agrego una imagen usando Imageview entonces se cae la app.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como pueden ver esa cruz es el imageview, y al compilar da este error.

```
04-06 23:16:12.117 408-453/system_process E/InputDispatcher: channel '53750588 com.example.fruttyappnew/com.example.fruttyappnew.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
```

también hay una linea que esta subrayada en azul le doy clic y me apunta a esta linea.

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2__nivel1);
```

nota(he probado con las imágenes que vienen en android por defecto esas grises, y funciona perfectamente.)

Aquí agrego la imagen en modo xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="116dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.27"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/adicion" />
```

Esta linea es la que siempre encuentro en el LogCat cuando tengo este error con las imágenes.

```
04-07 15:39:08.489 1183-1183/com.example.fruttyappnew A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 1183 (le.fruttyappnew)
```

Comment: ¿Puedes proporcionar más detalles? ¿Qué es esa imagen? un drawable xml, un imagen fija

Comment: amigo es la vista diseño. ese signo de "MAS" que ves es un imageview(imagen) las cuales tengo guardadas en la carpeta drawable.

Comment: cambia el atributo `app:srcCompat` por `android:src`

Comment: Hola @mauricio el mensaje que agregas no indica mucho, tu app se sube al dispositivo y se cierra o no puede generarse? Busca en el LogCat donde indica el mensaje "Caused by".

Comment: Claro Jorgesys♦, tengo genymotion y cuando emulo la app simplemente se cierra no se que mas poner porque busco ese "Caused by" que tanto mencionas pero no lo encuentro en el LogCat. lo extraño es que no es con todas las imágenes las que vienen por defecto en android funcionan correctamente.

Comment: Jorgesys♦ por si no me especifico bien lo único que quiero es que esa imagen que ves hay con ese símbolo(imageview) se muestre en el emulador. pero no lo hace.

Comment: Hola Jorgesys♦ al fin pude solucionar el error pero no se que hacen esas dos lineas de codigo ¿podrías ver mi respuesta y aclarármelo o decirme en donde puedo hacer esta pregunta? saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienen que ir a la parte de AndroidManifest y agregar estas dos lineas de código justo después de la etiqueta de apertura application.

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
android:largeHeap="true"
```

y ya esta.